# How to separate readable and unreadable images into different folders?

Tags: vb.net, photo

I have the folder `D:\both_img`. In that folder I have a bulk of both readable and unreadable `.bmp` images.

How can I move the unreadable images to a another folder?

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim openfiled1 As New OpenFileDialog
    If openfiled1.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openfiled1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do mean by _"unreadable"_? Visually unreadable? Unreadable by code?

Comment: You don't need a `PictureBox` for this.  That's for displaying an image.  What has that got to do with what you want?  Think about what you need to do and tackle it one stage at a time.  Obviously, if you want to do anything with the files in the folder then you need to be able to access the files in the folder. Have you researched that yet?  If not, why not? Only once you can access the files can you do anything with them.  One step at a time.

Comment: i have some many image.while opening those images an error massage appears that , cant read file header/file may be corrupted , or too large object file..

Comment: So iterate every file, try to open each and wrap that piece of code in a [**`Try/Catch` statement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement), then move the file if it reaches the `Catch` block (i.e. when the loading fails).

Comment: pls provide me a source code for that.

Comment: This is a fairly easy task to do. I provided you with the documentation for `Try/Catch` - you're gonna use that around the code that is prone to fail (to throw an error). You already know how to open an image, so all you need to do now is to learn how [**`Directory.GetFiles()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) works in order to iterate every file in the specified directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("D:\both_img")
Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
Dim fi As FileInfo
For Each fi In fiArr
    Try
      Dim image1 As Bitmap = CType(Image.FromFile(fi.FullName, True), Bitmap)
      fi.MoveTo(validFiledestPath) 'Move to valid file folder
    Catch ex As OutOfMemoryException
      fi.MoveTo(invalidFileDestPath) 'Move to invalid file folder
    End Try
Next fri
```

This code iterates all the files. Tries to open them using `Image.FromFile` and if it opens moves them to valid folder otherwise move to invalid folder.
[References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx)